# Why is my Query response returning Null Values?

Tags: java, mysql, reactjs, spring-boot, jpa

I have a customer class , What I want to do is call the customer firstname and Lastname fields alone from the Customer entity  to populate the Customer Name dropdown field in Investment Form. I added a projection using an interface but the response values are null .

Here is the **customer** class

```
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8348682056500740593L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String firstName ;
    private String lastName;
```

This is the **projection** class

```
public interface CustomerInter {
    
    String getFirstName();
    String getLastName();
    
}
```

This is the **repository** class

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerAccountRepo extends JpaRepository <Customer, Long  > 

{

     Optional<Customer> findById(Long id);
     
    // Optional<Customer> findByFirstNameAndLastName(String firstName , String lastName);

     
     @Query(value="select c.firstName, c.lastName from Customer c")
     List<CustomerInter> findByFirstNameAndLastName();
}
```

This is the **Service** class

```
@Service
public class CustomerAccountService {
    
    @Autowired  
    private CustomerAccountRepo custRepo;



    public List<CustomerInter> getFirstNameAndLastNameOnly() throws Exception {
    //    LOGGER.info("Inside getAllCustomerFirst&LastName");
        List<CustomerInter> customerName = custRepo.findByFirstNameAndLastName();
        return customerName;
        }
    
  }
```

This is the **controller** class

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:3000"})
@RestController
public class CustomerController {
    
        @Autowired
        CustomerAccountService customerRepo;
    
        @GetMapping(value="/customerFirstAndLastName")
         public List<CustomerInter> getFirstNameAndLastNameOnly() throws Exception
         {
             
            return customerRepo.getFirstNameAndLastNameOnly();
             
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do will not work this way.

First of all you have a `JpaRepository <Customer, Long>`, the type of the entity is `Customer` and the id `Long`. So the queries of this `JpaRepo` will handle **only** `Customer` objects.

If you have a need for objects only with the `firstName` and `lastName` then create a
`class` (DTO) which has only those and change your query to this:

```java
....

@Query(value="SELECT new path.to.your.package.CustomerDTO(c.firstName, c.lastName) " +
        "FROM Customer c")
     List<CustomerDTO> findByFirstNameAndLastName();
```

P.S.: You need a constructor for your `DTO` as seen above.