# Why do i only get the values when returning an object from a query?

Tags: java, spring-data

```
public interface UserDao {

    User getUserById(Long id);

    void saveUser(User user);

    List<UserDto> getAllUsers();

    boolean isExistUserByEmail(String email);

    boolean isExistUserByUserName(String userName);

    // get users by id list
    List<User> getUsersByIdIn(List<Long> idList);

    // get all active users
    List<UserDto> getAllActiveUsers();

    User getUserByEmail(String email);

    void saveAllUsers(List<User> userList);
    
    List<Object[]> getAllInstructors();
  
}
```

This my dao impl method

```
@Override 
    public List<Object[]> getAllInstructors() {
        return userRepository.getAllInstructors();
    }
```

This is the query from my repository layer

```
@Query(value = "select distinct u.first_name, u.last_name, u.full_name, u.id from public.user u inner join public.users_group ug on u.id = ug.user_id and ug.group_list_id=1 WHERE status=1 ORDER BY u.id DESC", nativeQuery = true)
```

This is the method in my controller layer

```
@GetMapping("/instructors")
    public List<Object[]> getAllIntsructors() {
        return userService.getAllInstructors();
    }
```

Result when I call the api on postman
[image: Result when I call the api on postman]

The result I expect is:

```
first_name: "Iresha"
second_name: "Vishwakala"
```

But I don't get the key. I only get an array of objects showing me the values.

Comment: Your query is returning strings.

Comment: Change `List<Object[]>` to `List<DTO Name>`

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using your Repo is not a good practice. To be honest I have never seen it before.

This would be the correct way to do it:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long> // Here the first is the Entity which will be fetched by this repo, and the second is the type of ID that this Entity has.
{
    // I am supposing that your entity is UserEntity and has an ID of type Long.
    // Here come the queries which must return primitives or UserEntity (list, set etc.)
    // An example query would be:
    @Query(value = "....", nativeQuery = true) List<UserEntity> getUsersAsYouWant();
}
```

The `JpaRepository` makes use of Java Generics (hence the `<>`), that is why you must supply the class the types that it has to map the DB rows/data to. If you want to return specific types/Dtos/List you may use the same Repo but with different Query building (not native but [JPQL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_jpql.htm)). But that would be yet another question. If you want to check more, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69539192/7954021).